# Is there a known size limit of the thread local storage in a prevalent modern OS?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-local-storage

When I use `thread_local`, `_Thread_local`, `__thread`, or `__declspec(thread)`, the compiler seems to allocate a thread local storage upon thread creation and store the address in the `fs` or `gs` register in an x86 derived system.

In this context, is there something like 'thread local storage overflow'?

Comment: There isn't any limit other than the same limit as for variables with static storage duration (i.e. global variables). TLS data ends up on the heap, but because the entire TLS section has to be allocated continuously, you might get problems with a large TLS section when the heap is fragmented.

Comment: @FUZxxl: That "continuous allocation"  sounds like one particular implementation. I don't see a problem with a linked list of TLS segments. Say we have 4K TLS pages, and the last pointer on each page points to the next segment. TLS variables are already commonly expressed as offsets, the only change is that for a TLS offset > 4kB we subtract 4kB from the offset and (recursively) look it up in the next TLS page.

Comment: @MSalters You could do this, but such an implementation would be horribly slow, so nobody does this.

Comment: @FUZxxl: True, a linked list isn't the fastest data structure, but it's the easiest to describe in a 600 char comment, It shows both that multiple implementations are possible, as well as non-contiguous allocations.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, other implementations are possible but nobody implements TLS this way. My comment from above concerns *real* implementations of thread local storage, not designs made-up specifically to disprove my application-oriented remarks. If this was about theory, you would be correct, but this is about engineering where what is actually done matters more than the theoretical extent of standards.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Your initial comment states that TLS section _has to be_ allocated continuously (necessity). You can't prove necessity from "real implementations". If you're certain about all implementations, you might say that "the entire TLS section _is_ allocated continuously" (descriptive).

Comment: @MSalters Notice that I'm talking about a »TLS section,« which is *one possible way* of implementing TLS. A section is a continuous memory area with a given set of attributes and a specific purpose. It has to be allocated continuously by definition. Now, you could implement TLS differently *without* a TLS section. The only relevant standard that actually speaks about (memory) sections is the SysV ABI specification, neither POSIX nor ISO 9899 actually know the concept of a section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93584/discussion-between-msalters-and-fuzxxl).

Answer (score 2):

There are limits.  Each system will be different, but on Windows, there is a limited data section which is mapped thread specifically.  The size of this section is limited.

Older versions of windows used this directly, and would fail when new items were created.

Last time I checked on Windows 7+, this had gone (OS uses 1 slot for the whole DLL - as a redirection to a thread local map), but there was a different limitation, which limited the number of unique slots available.  Each DLL loaded used a slot, and thus there was a limit on the number of DLLs which could use thread local storage.

See also [wikipedia : thread local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage#Windows_implementation)