# Any size limit on the __thread buffer?

Tags: c, thread-local-storage

I want to use a buffer on the level of thread. But I think malloc/free in every function is boring. They can share the buffer.

`static __thread char my_buff[BUF_SIZE] = {0};`

But is there any size limit on this buffer? If there is, how to check it?

Comment: Sounds somewhat limited.  I have never understood thread-local storage - seems like 'per thread global variables' to me:(   Maybe you could suggest a use-case to clear it up for me?  I do use large pools,of buffers to share/communicate data between threads, but I don't thing that is what you are suggesting....

Comment: @MartinJames I don't use the buffer between threads. I only use it in the functions which are absolutely thread-safe. Those functions can share such buffer, don't need to malloc at the head, and free at the end or some error branchs.

Comment: @lxyscls: Afaik the TLS is allocated with malloc() when the the thread is created (although if you dynamically load modules everything gets a bit more complicated because every module can have its own thread-local segment, and a module's thread-local storage for a particular thread may be allocated lazily). So the size limit will be what malloc() can find, which might vary from moment to moment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310208/is-there-a-known-size-limit-of-the-thread-local-storage-in-a-prevalent-modern-os This question is essentially a duplicate but I don’t vote to close because it has a very partial answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thread_local` objects are dynamically allocated when a thread is created (or at any rate before the object is used, courtesy of the "as-if" clause). Nothing in the C standard specifies how the allocation is done, but on many systems the standard library's dynamic allocation functions are used. So there is probably no limit as long as dynamically allocated memory is available. (The standard also doesn't say anything about when this storage is returned to whatever storage manager allocated it; it is certainly possible to imagine an implementation which does not return thread local segments until the application terminates, preferring to recycle segments from terminated threads to newly-created ones. But I don't believe that's common.)

Note that at least on statically-linked executables, thread-local objects are allocated for every thread, whether or not the thread uses the object. Modules which are dynamically loaded can also include thread-local objects, so the amount of thread-local storage needed for a thread can change as modules are loaded and unloaded. The implementation of this feature requires an extra level of indirection accessing thread-local storage, and also commonly involves lazy allocation of TLS segments (not individual objects).

I really only have experience with ELF systems; I searched a bit in the usual places to verify that `thread_local` should work in roughly the same way on modern Windows. Legacy platforms may not have the feature, so you might be limiting portability by using it. I wouldn't normally let that stop me, but it does seem prudent to check the platform documentation for platforms which you intend to support.